# change open from GoogleMap Pin to be standard link

Tags: jquery, wordpress, api, google-maps

I'm hoping someone can look at this and tell me where the fix is. Basically i'm using a plugin for wordpress called MapifyPro. It is to call Googlemaps into a site etc.

Long story short, the pins open up a window when clicked, I need them to just open normally, just to load the link in _self nothing more complicated than that.

Can anyone see the issue in the jQuery below and let me know how to fix it?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var map_instance = jQuery.MapifyPro.Instance.create(<?php echo $mpfy_instances; ?>);
map_instance.routes = <?php echo json_encode($routes); ?>;
map_instance.tooltip_background = <?php echo json_encode($tooltip_background); ?>;

var center = <?php echo json_encode($center); ?>;
var zoom = {
    'zoom': <?php echo $zoom_level; ?>,
    'enabled': <?php echo ($zoom_enabled) ? 'true' : 'false'; ?>
};
var search_radius = <?php echo $search_radius; ?>;
var settings = {
    'mapTypeId': <?php echo json_encode($google_map_mode); ?>,
    'map_mode': <?php echo json_encode($mode); ?>,
    'search_center': <?php echo json_encode($search_center); ?>,
    'filters_center': <?php echo json_encode($filters_center); ?>,
    'style': <?php echo $google_map_style; ?>,
    'clustering_enabled': <?php echo json_encode($clustering_enabled); ?>,
    'background': <?php echo json_encode($background); ?>
};
if (settings.map_mode == 'image') {
    settings['image_source'] = <?php echo json_encode($tileset_url); ?>;
}
var inst = new jQuery.MapifyPro.Google(center, zoom, search_radius, <?php echo json_encode($pins); ?>, map_instance, settings);

jQuery(map_instance.container).find('a.mpfy-pin[href=#]').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});

var is_phone = jQuery.MapifyPro.isPhone();
var is_tablet = jQuery.MapifyPro.isTablet();
var is_touch_device = jQuery.MapifyPro.isTouchDevice();

if (is_phone) {
    jQuery(map_instance.container).find('a.mpfy-pin').not('.mpfy-pin[href=#]').bind('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        jQuery('#fancybox-loading').show();
        jQuery.get(jQuery(this).attr('href'), {}, function(response) {
            jQuery('body').addClass('mpfy-popup-open');
            jQuery('#fancybox-loading').hide();

            jQuery('.mpfy-popup-cnt').html(response);
            jQuery('.mpfy-popup').show();

            jQuery('.mpfy-pin-popup .gallery .list li a').click(function() {
                jQuery('.mpfy-pin-popup .gallery .list li a').removeClass('active');
                jQuery(this).addClass('active');

                var index = jQuery('.mpfy-pin-popup .gallery .list li a').index(this);
                jQuery('.mpfy-pin-popup .gallery .holder .item').hide();
                jQuery('.mpfy-pin-popup .gallery .holder .item:eq(' + index.toString() + ')').show();
                jQuery('.mpfy-pin-popup .caption').show().html(jQuery(this).next().html());
                if (!jQuery(this).next().html()) {
                    jQuery('.mpfy-pin-popup .caption').hide();
                }
                return false;
            });

            jQuery('.mpfy-pin-popup .gallery .list li a:first').click();

            if (jQuery('.popup-slider .list li').length > 1) {
                jQuery('.popup-slider .list').jcarousel({
                    scroll: 1
                });
            }

            var gallery_holder = jQuery('.mpfy-popup .gallery').get(0);
            var hammertime = Hammer(gallery_holder, {
                drag: false,
                prevent_mouseevents: true,
                transform: false,
                swipe_velocity: 0.1
            });
            hammertime.on("swipeleft", function(e) {
                var target = jQuery('.mpfy-pin-popup .gallery .list li a.active').parent().next().find('a:first');
                if (target.length) {
                    target.click();
                    var index = jQuery('.mpfy-pin-popup .gallery .list li a').index(target);
                    jQuery('.popup-slider .list').jcarousel('scroll', index + 1);
                }
                e.preventDefault();
            });
            hammertime.on("swiperight", function(e) {
                var target = jQuery('.mpfy-pin-popup .gallery .list li a.active').parent().prev().find('a:first');
                if (target.length) {
                    target.click();
                    var index = jQuery('.mpfy-pin-popup .gallery .list li a').index(target);
                    jQuery('.popup-slider .list').jcarousel('scroll', index + 1);
                }
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });

        return false;
    });
    jQuery('.mpfy-popup .close').click(function() {
        jQuery('.mpfy-popup').hide();
        jQuery('body').removeClass('mpfy-popup-open');
        jQuery.MapifyPro.hideTooltips();
        return false;
    });
} else {
    jQuery(map_instance.container).find('a.mpfy-pin:not([href=#])').fancybox({
        type: 'ajax',
        autoDimensions: false,
        width: 960,
        height: 595,
        padding: 0,
        scrolling: 'auto',
        overlayColor: "#000",
        overlayOpacity: 0.85,
        beforeLoad: function() {
            jQuery('#fancybox-wrap').addClass('mpfy-override-fancybox');
        },
        afterShow: function(){
            jQuery('body').addClass('mpfy-popup-open');
            jQuery('.mpfy-pin-popup .gallery .list li a').click(function() {
                var index = jQuery('.mpfy-pin-popup .gallery .list li a').index(this);
                jQuery('.mpfy-pin-popup .gallery .holder .item').hide();
                jQuery('.mpfy-pin-popup .gallery .holder .item:eq(' + index.toString() + ')').show();
                jQuery('.mpfy-pin-popup .caption').show().html(jQuery(this).next().html());
                if (!jQuery(this).next().html()) {
                    jQuery('.mpfy-pin-popup .caption').hide();
                }
                return false;
            });

            jQuery('.mpfy-pin-popup .gallery .list li a:first').click();

            if (jQuery('.popup-slider .list li').length > 7) {
                jQuery('.popup-slider .list').jcarousel({
                    scroll: 1
                });
            }

            jQuery.fancybox.reposition();

            jQuery('.mpfy-share').appendTo('.fancybox-outer')
        },
        afterClose: function() {
            jQuery('body').removeClass('mpfy-popup-open');
            jQuery('#fancybox-wrap').removeClass('mpfy-override-fancybox');
        }
    });
    if (is_tablet) {
        jQuery('#fancybox-wrap').addClass('fancybox-tablet');
    }
}

<?php if (isset($_GET['mpfy-pin'])) : ?>
    var open_pin = <?php echo $_GET['mpfy-pin']; ?>;
    (function(instance) {

        setTimeout(function() {
            var a = jQuery(instance.container).find('a.mpfy-pin[data-id="' + open_pin + '"]');
            if (a.length) {
                for (var i = 0; i < instance.markers.length; i++) {
                    var m = instance.markers[i];
                    if (m._mpfy.pin_id == open_pin) {
                        m.getMap().setCenter(m.getPosition());
                        break;
                    }
                }
                a.trigger('click');
            }
        }, 1);

    })(map_instance);
<?php endif; ?>});
```

I know it has something to do with the bit in the middle area stating the ajax container. I just cant find a way of just making it open a standard link.

Any help would be great!

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it using:

```
jQuery(map_instance.container).find('a.mpfy-pin').not('.mpfy-pin[href=#]').bind('click', function() {
        window.open("<?php echo add_query_arg('', '', get_permalink($p->ID)); ?>", "_self");
    });
```